# Laravel | Polymorphic relationship from morphed model

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I am creating a polymorphic relationship which defaults to null, as it doesn't have an association originally.

I then create the association and I want to be able to update the polymorphic table to have a link between the original and the morphed class.

post_images:

`| id | post_id | width | height | created_at | updated_at`

files:

`| id | fileable_type | fileable_id | file_disk_id | created_at | updated_at`

So basically, inside of the polymorphic table the type and the id they default to null as it has to be processed first and converted to a standard format etc.

I then create the associated row inside of the morphed table, however I am unsure how to update the polymorphic to have the type and the id from the morphed table.

I have tried to do something like `$post->images()->create(...);` and then try and do something like `$file->where('id', $fileId)->firstOrFail()->associate($post);` but this just seems to return null.

So the current process is:

Upload the file -> creates a row in the files table which contains the polymorphic relationships but columns are defaulted to null.

Standardize the file -> the file then gets converted and compressed into a standard format that is used for the site.

Create post_images row -> The site then creates a row for post_images table which then needs to link the update the files row to contain the new polymorphic relation.

Eloquent relationships:

File.php

```
public function fileable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

PostImage.php

```
public function file()
{
    return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable');
}
```

Post.php

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostImage::class);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Eloquent relationships?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson I have updated the original post to contain the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** you should just be able to call the save method on the relationship. For example:

```php
$post->file()->save($file)
```